# Change an unordered list's appearance from a dot to an underscore

Tags: css

A client asked me if I could change the appearance of unordered lists throughout a website.

Now, using the default dot, they look like this:

> - A normal
> - unordered list

The desired output would be (using the underscore `_`):

> _  A normal
>   _  Unordered list

How could I achieve that using CSS? (if possible)

Comment: see answers below. I would have to agree with both answers. CSS or an image could do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that using CSS.

HTML:

```
<ul>  
    <li>test</li>  
    <li>test</li>  
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li:before {
    content: '_ ';
}
```

Here's a relevant fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q8v4k/1/

Comment: Not true. But you do have to define a !DOCTYPE for it to work in IE7.

Comment: Just going off of your jfiddle.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to provide your own image as a bullet template.

```
list-style-image: url(bullet_underscore.png);
```

Comment: True that for browsers that don't support the pure CSS version. I guess I'll have to switch CSS depending on the browser then.